# USB sound device not recognized

Tags: 10.10, sound, usb

I have a USB sound device that used to work back when I ran other versions of Ubuntu.  Now I can only partially see the device.  I have tried many things I saw in Google  searches, but none solve my problem.

`cat /proc/asound/cards` sees the device as card 0

- aplay -l shows C-Media USB Audio as card 0
- alsamixer sees the device
- asoundconf list does not show the device
- sound preferences shows no hardware
- asoundconf-gtk set the device to pulseaudio, but fails with python errors ending in 
  `ValueError: too many values to unpack` in the function set_default_card.  I think this  is the cause of my problem.

The device is a Sony virtual phones wireless headphone amplifier.

Comment: Is the device visible in the Sound Preferences in the GUI?

Comment: no, there are no devices listed

Comment: Does it show in pavucontrol?

Comment: no, it does not show in pavucontrol.  I see only Dummy Output

Comment: I'd file a bug.  `ubuntu-bug -s audio`

Comment: bug #662156 filed against pulseaudio

Comment: the bug was closed with the comment that the device name is an

Comment: inappropriate choice by the manufacturer and that the fix is to

Comment: remove ~/.asound* and /etc/asound.conf  The fix did not work.

Comment: I can use the device with VLC, but not Firefox, for example.

Comment: After some updates to 10.10 ALSA stopped supporting the device.

Answer (score 3):

[Bug report here](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/662156)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I found a bug in the asoundconf script. (It did not allow comments in some configuration file(s) after a parameter-value-set.)
You can find a fixed version at http://www.tu-harburg.de/~sedt1131/asoundconf which solved the problem for me. (I have not found a proper way to report the bug, so I started by uploading the fixed version to my webspace...)

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the onboard sound and USB worked.   I sometimes have to

'alsa restart'  to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and entering `pulseaudio -k` in the terminal did not fix it completely, as I also needed to end whatever audio mixer was associated with my desktop environment; for KDE, for example, you enter in the terminal

```
killall kmix
pulseaudio -k
kmix
```

and then your USB sound device should be detected.